# When I edit a Site Column, the updates aren't propagating down to the list I'm using the Site Column in

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, column-validation

When I edit Column Validation in a Site Column, it doesn't propagate down to the list I'm using the column in. Isn't that the point?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the specific list> click on the site column in this list and make sure there is a column validation in it.

And make sure following option is Yes in site column settings:

[image]

Comment: I've done both of these, and still nothing. I've been able to add a handful of them successfully, but some are just being stubborn. One is a simple text field, no validation, etc. But it just won't show in Crawled properties.

Comment: What's the really issue?Column validation work or column not show in crawled properties?